# ANT Script to Compile/Build Multiple Projects

Tags: java, ant, multiple-projects, build-tools

I want to Compile 2 projects in my workspace, in which projectB is dependent on projectA.

ProjectA

```
 |----src
 |----build.xml
```

ProjectB

```
 |----src
 |----build.xml
```

To Say I'm importing some packages from ProjectB. Now I have 2 Tasks

1. How do I Compile ProjectB ?
2. How do write ANT build.xml(master-build.xml) for both the Projects?**strong text**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Master-Build.xml, create targets to build project A and B and a target to build all:

Example :

```
    <target name="build.projectB" depends="build.projectA">
         <ant antfile="${buildB}/deploy.xml" dir="." />
    </target>
```

For the dependencies of your project B in your Master-Build.xml : 
- use the keyword depends="build.projectA" on the projectB target

Example :

```
<target name="A"/>
<target name="B" depends="A"/>
```